# When I cast object to its supertype do I access the original or overriden methods?

Tags: java, inheritance

Consider the following Java class and another class that overrides its method `hello()`.

```
class Greeter {
    public void hello(String name)  {
        System.out.println("Hello "+name+".");
    }
}

class Greeter_mean extends Greeter {
    public void hello(String name)  {
        System.out.println("You are NOT welcome, "+name+"!");
    }
}
```

Now I'll create an instance of `Greeter_mean` but I'll cast it to `Greeter`.

```
Greeter test = (Greeter)new Greeter_mean();
test.hello("Tomáš");
```

What will the output be?

Comment: Why don't you just try it?

Comment: I hope you know the output? Just run it.

Comment: Reference type casting does not change the identity of the referenced object.

Comment: That's called [Polymorphism](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/polymorphism.html). Read more about it.

Comment: What if I just wanted to know while not having access to JDK?

Comment: You can use an online IDE or you could read the documentation or anything else written on the subject.

Comment: Output will be `Hello Tomáš`

Comment: @TomášZato: Then just wait until you do, rather than posting a redundant question.  (And anyway, you always have access to a JDK, e.g. http://ideone.com.)

Comment: According to the fact, that there are answers proposing both options, the question is not redundant.

Comment: In your case you are not overriding the method ... rather hiding it.

Comment: Well, Netbeans propose `@Override` annotation for code like the one I posted. So who's wrong?

Comment: According to what fact? What answers? The one that is downvoted?

Comment: As well as @Rahul's comment. Obviously, the thing is not *that* obvious. As well, I expected some explanation along with the direct answer. I do believe that we're building knowledge base here, on SO. Not solving asker's problems.

Comment: @TomášZato: But this knowledge is in the first few chapters of any introductory Java book.  We're not here to replicate the content of introductory books.

Comment: We also expect a certain amount of effort on your side. Have you gone through any of the related questions? What about them does not answer your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Output will obviously correspond to

```
System.out.println("You are NOT welcome, "+name+"!");
```

having the subclass method is superclass will only allow your code to compile.

i.e `test.hello("Tomáš");` after type cast.

However at runtime method of Greeter_mean  is called as the instance if really of type Greeter_mean.

Answer (score -2):

You could imagine object extension as a shell to the original object. If you cast it to supertype, it's gonna lose its shell. (Well until you cast it back)
At least this is how I learned it.

Comment: What is `oject extension`? Do you mean inheritance? Do you mean casting? What does the shell represent?